# conditional actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this actionlink that allows the user to support an index view.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Opened Date", "Index", new {sortOrder= ViewBag.OpenedDateParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter})
```

This where it is handled in the controller

```
ViewBag.OpenedDateParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "OpenedDate desc" : "Date";
```

I would like to sort asc if the current sort is desc and vice versa. Do I use ?: to evaluate the condition in the action link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have this in your controller action. It will set the ViewBag.OpenedDateParm to `asc` if the current value is `desc` and viceversa

```
 ViewBag.OpenedDateParm = sortOrder == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
```

In your View,

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Opened Date", "Index","YourControllerName",
           new { sortOrder = ViewBag.OpenedDateParm,
                 currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter },null)
```